# Printing dbt invocation_command in the logs

Tags: logging, jinja2, monitoring, dbt

So I'm using dbt core with snowflake data warehouse. I'm using dbt in some Kubeflow components in a pipeline.. and when the components run, I want to be able to see which dbt command it has been invoked to run this component.
I know I can show the input parameters for a pipeline.. but my main question how can I print what invocation_command was triggered for dbt.
I have read many documentation webpages and I found this invocation_command variable that has the value, but I could not find how I can get its value and then print it in the logs that dbt usually prints.

Thanks in advance

I have tried
`dbt --debug run`
but then the log is too too long.. I only want the regular logs, with the `invocation_command` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished by running some Jinja in [`on-run-start`](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/project-configs/on-run-start-on-run-end). This will print the invocation command in the log.

```
on-run-start: "{{ log('invocation_command: ' ~ flags.INVOCATION_COMMAND, info=true) }}"
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! this is exactly what I needed.
Can I ask you please, how can I read more of this "flags" like to learn more what I can find and use.. also is this "log" part of Jinja ?

Comment: [Flags](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/flags) and [log](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/log) are both specific to dbt